# php select query to sum quantity of items sold order by date

Tags: php, mysql

Need some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Here is my first table: table_bill

```
id   table_id status    added_date
73      1       1       9/1/2013 0:00
74      8       1       9/1/2013 0:00
75      17      1       9/1/2013 0:00
76      15      1       9/1/2013 0:00
77      20      1       9/1/2013 0:00
78      10      1       9/1/2013 0:00
79      4       1       9/1/2013 0:00
81      8       1       9/1/2013 0:00
82      16      1       9/1/2013 0:00
83      17      1       9/1/2013 0:00
84      14      1       9/1/2013 0:00
85      10      1       9/1/2013 0:00
86      9       1       9/1/2013 0:00
87      8       1       9/2/2013 0:00
88      11      1       9/2/2013 0:00
89      14      1       9/2/2013 0:00
90      2       1       9/2/2013 0:00
91      12      1       9/2/2013 0:00
92      30      1       9/2/2013 0:00
93      14      1       9/2/2013 0:00
94      5       1       9/2/2013 0:00
95      10      1       9/2/2013 0:00
96      2       1       9/2/2013 0:00
97      10      1       9/2/2013 0:00
98      11      1       9/3/2013 0:00
99      8       1       9/3/2013 0:00
100     11      1       9/3/2013 0:00
101     12      1       9/3/2013 0:00
102     20      1       9/3/2013 0:00
103     4       1       9/3/2013 0:00
```

And here is my second table: table_data

```
id  bill_id  item_id quantity
166     73      21      2
167     73      31      1
168     73      115     1
169     73      183     1
170     73      131     8
171     73      170     4
172     73      63      4
173     74      103     1
174     74      187     1
175     74      101     1
177     74      207     1
178     74      136     5
179     74      170     2
180     74      65      2
181     75      25      2
182     75      36      1
183     75      180     1
184     75      65      2
185     75      108     1
187     75      135     2
188     75      141     2
189     75      170     2
190     76      202     1
191     76      118     1
192     76      136     5
193     76      170     3
194     76      63      4
195     77      188     2
196     77      110     1
197     77      63      5
```

I want to get the sum of each item sold in a day datewise

Here is my query for the same....

```
$sql = "SELECT ocs.item_id, os.added_date, ocs.quantity FROM table_bill os, table_data ocs WHERE os.id = ocs.bill_id";
```

However, i am getting sold item results multiple time for a day

For ex: if item number 1 is sold to 5 different customers in a day, i am getting 5 different results for item number 1, i want the total number of sale for that item number in a day.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I forgot to mention anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to total things, you have to use the `SUM()` aggregation function, and specify the grouping with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT ocs.item_id, os.added_date, SUM(ocs.quantity) total
FROM table_bill os
JOIN table_data ocs
ON os.is = ocs.bill_id
GROUP BY ocs.item_id, os.added_date
```